# Setting up Dual-boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 screwed up GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, grubrescue

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire M5-581T that came with Windows 8 preloaded.

After several attempts at trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, I finally managed to boot from a LiveUSB and install it.  However, due to Windows finicky UEFI setup, this didn't all go as planned.

In order to boot from a LiveUSB, I entered my BIOS and changed the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy BIOS.  This allowed me to change the boot order and properly install Ubuntu 12.10 onto my partitioned drive.

Ubuntu was working fine, but when I rebooted, there was no GRUB menu asking whether I'd like to load into Windows or Linux.  It simply loaded me directly into Linux as if Windows wasn't there.

I figured it was due to my being in Legacy BIOS boot mode, so I changed it back to UEFI.  Then, only Windows would load, with no menu for choosing Ubuntu.

In retrospect, I'd have kept this over the disaster that is currently my computer.  I went back into Linux by switching into Legacy BIOS again and install boot-repair.  I ran it on the Recommended Settings, thinking it would install my much needed boot menu.  It didn't.

Now, I can't get either OS to load.  When I reboot in UEFI, I get errors stating:
`Windows Boot Manager has been blocked by the current security policy` and then `HDD0:  has been blocked...etc`.  I can't disable Secure Boot while still loading in UEFI mode.

Booting in Legacy BIOS leaves me in the grub rescue prompt with the error `file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod'`.

Prior to rebooting after running boot-repair, I was given the pastebin: [paste.ubuntu.com/1618833](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1618833) and was told that my `.efi` file was located in `sda2/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`.

I am becoming desperate.  Please advise me in loading into at least one of my operating systems...

NOTE: I have read many of the similar posts, but none address the problem with necessary depth.  Most others' problems were solved by boot-repair, not caused by it.

Comment: if you change mode from UEFI to Legacy, you must reinstall windows in Legacy mode. In a word both ubuntu and Windows must be installed in one mode either legacy or UEFI. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @Web-E Yes, but how can I install anything without first accessing one of the operating systems?  Thank you for the link.

Comment: Repair using windows recovery disk. Hopefully you have it (shipped with laptop) or you created using recovery media creator. That should have been the first step. If not, and if you have ubuntu live disk, just boot it with it.Take backups if required. Hopefully there will be a recovery partition, inside that there should be `.wim` image. Search google for wim deployment. You will get plenty of guide & this time install windows using Legacy mode.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your mistake has been to install two operating systems (Windows and ubuntu) in different modes:

1. Windows 8 is istalled in UEFI Secure mode
2. ubuntu is installed in BIOS Legacy mode

You can only switch between the modes via the BIOS/UEFI.

Please try the following:

1. Restart you system with the power-button
2. Immendiately thereafter press  to enter the BIOS/UEFI
3. Press F10 and set the system to UEFI Boot and Secure boot enabled. Then save the settings
4. Press F9 to enter the "boot options". In the "boot manager" try the listed files one by one. Hopefully one boots. Alternatively let us know what is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing day one with the same laptop! Freaked me out. But it got better. I really learned about the UEFI bootloader and intel.

you need to youtube "intel uefi" .  intel puts out a series of three videos were they install windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 on a machine with a uefi type device.

What you need is a shim added to the bootloader. All is explained in the videos. Just make sure you dont lock your bootloader. I mean secure boot. That locked me out of the machine totally. It would not boot from usb, cd, anything. Its like locking your keys in your car with the engine running.

After all said and done, i now dual boot with grub2. At start up i see my options for ubuntu or windows. For three months, ive used windows, three times.

I know you got into your machine by now, but this post is for others now discovering the wonderful world of the uefi bootloader with secure boot! Thanks malicious hackers.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please, when you answer a question, provide the steps to solve the issue at hand and any experience that may help to reach a closure. Do not refer to other sites or post just links.